# How to connect celery with flask and Redis as message broker and do machine learning predictions

Tags: python, flask, redis, celery

I am doing inference of a machine learning PyTorch model and want to use celery and Redis for queuing prediction. I have written the inference code in the flask as a rest API and now got confused about how to add celery tasks and Redis message broker.

```py
# flask rest API code for inference
response = {}
@app.route('/predict', methods=["POST", "GET"])
def predict():
    if request.method=='POST':
        solute = request.form["solute"]
        solvent = request.form["solvent"]

    else:
        solute = request.args.get("solute")
        solvent = request.args.get("solvent")

    results = predictions(solute, solvent)
    
    response["predictions"] = results[0].item()
    response["interaction_map"] = (results[1].detach().numpy()).tolist()
    return flask.jsonify({'result': response})
```

```py
# celery tasks
from celery import Celery, current_task
from celery.result import AsyncResult

REDIS_URL = 'redis://redis:6379/0'
BROKER_URL = 'redis://redis:6379/0'

CELERY = Celery('tasks',
                backend=REDIS_URL,
                broker=BROKER_URL)

def get_job(job_id):
    return AsyncResult(job_id, app=CELERY)
```

I have tried running it using `celery worker -b redis://localhost:6379 --app= main.celery -l` (here `b` is broker), then I got the error

> Error: No such option: -b.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is confusing you? Is there a particular problem with this code?

Comment: I have written this following the blogs on the internet. when I add `celery.task` to the top of my app.route is it correct or not. @mkrieger1

Comment: yes i have tried running it using `celery worker -b redis://localhost:6379 --app= main.celery -l` then I got the error `Error: No such option: -b`. here b is broker. I don't know whether I am doing it right or totally wrong.  @mkrieger1

Comment: You celery app is called tasks so try, `celery -A tasks worker`